# How to add facebook plugin in cordova using cli

Tags: android, facebook, cordova

I am using cordova 3.3.0 cli.I found the documentation for manual installation which is for eclipse /xcode project. There is documantation for phonegap build also which we does in config.xml.I just want to install Facebook plugin to my cordova project which i am building through cordova CLI

**Update**  : I came over from the problem.Thanks to Kal for his Help. I wrote a complete tutorial for it .
[My Tutorial for facebook plugin](http://javacourseblog.blogspot.in/2014/01/facebook-login-logout-using-cordova-330.html)

Comment: hi, do u have any tutorials for sending sms using plugin for cordova project at CLI?

Answer (score 5):

Actually, CLI works you just need to add the `APP_ID` and `APP_NAME` variables to your command. Something like this:

```
C:\myProject>cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin --variable APP_ID=your_facebook_app_id --variable APP_NAME=your_facebook_app_name
```

I got it installed this way but not sure if the app is functional or not. Something to test.

**update:**

I had an issue with phonegap build giving me the error `One of your plugins requires a parameter: APP_ID, APP_NAME`. That was because I didn't add those variables to the config.xml file.

This solved it

```
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect">
 <param name="APP_ID" value="your_facebook_app_id" />
 <param name="APP_NAME" value="your_facebook_app_name" />
</gap:plugin>`
```

Everything works fine now! I hope this help someone.

**update 2:**

Please remember to modify the plugin.xml file under root/plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect/plugin.xml

```
<preference name="APP_ID" />
<preference name="APP_NAME" />
```

Comment: did you add these lines  inside www folder in root

Comment: First command worked but now got struck in  "One of your plugins requires a parameter: APP_ID, APP_NAME"

Comment: i am doing so but still throughing error. You meant proj_folder/www ?

Comment: when you build/compile your project the root config.xml gets copied to your platform config.xml be that iOS, Android ... etc

Comment: okay thanks a lot its worked I changed the config.xml file

<param name="APP_ID" value="288492194593093" />
<param name="APP_NAME" value="FriendString" />. The cordova documentation says uts typo from them

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46148/discussion-between-ashish-nautiyal-and-kal)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would help if you precise which plugin exactly you are trying to install...

In case it's the facebook connect plugin [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin), then you could try to install it this way :

```
cd yourprojectname
cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin
```

but it seems it does not work yet and you will have to perform manual installation :(

quote from readme.md:

> This plugin is based on plugman. To install it to your app, simply
> execute plugman as follows; **It does not currently work with plugman at
> all. WORK IN PROGRESS**

so I think you will have to wait a little more to be able to install it using the CLI...